# Redirecting from http:// to http:// www

Tags: apache, http, redirect

I'm doing a site and tested it in a Pingdom page speed test - I'm getting information saying that the re-direct from `http://` to `http://www` is taking around 900ms.  If you were to theoretically remove this redirect the site loads in about 600ms.

Is there anyway of controlling this or, more specifically removing this redirect? Or is this redirect an action that all apache servers do?

Please excuse my ignorance on the subject, but it's hard to find out any proper information on this.

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you want (after user enters `http://example.com` in browser address bar) the url in address bar to change to `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: I would like to remove the www version.  For instance I've looked on pingdom at a couple of other sites and they only have the  http:// version not both showing?  For instance if you put unlikely.studio into pingdom it doesn't have the www version show up?  I'm new to all of this.  Thanks @DusanBajic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem - the site address in my Wordpress general settings was set to the `www` version which was causing the redirect.  All solved now.